# How to make my strength stat increase how much counter increases by If i upgrade strength

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So at the moment I have a skill tree and my initial value of strength set to one. this is a clicker game so I was wondering how I make a function so if I add one to my strength stat instead of getting +1 to my counter every time I get +2 and so on if i upgrade strength again.

I haven't tried much because im clueless on what to do
I have this so far

```
def Strengt(event=None):
    if rebirth.get()>=1:
        Strength.set(1),  counter.set(counter.get() + 1)
def Strengthup(event=None):
    if rebirth.get()>=2:
        Strength.set(Strength.get()+1), 
skillpoint.set(skillpoint.get()-1)
```

I will post what my onclick function looks like

```
counter = tk.IntVar()
Ant = tk.IntVar()
autoclicker = tk.IntVar()
rebirth = tk.IntVar()
skillpoint = tk.IntVar()
Hitpoints = tk.IntVar()
Manapoints = tk.IntVar()
Strength = tk.IntVar()

def onClick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1)
def Hitpoint(event=None):
    if rebirth.get()>=1:
        Hitpoints.set(10)
def Manapoint(event=None):
    if rebirth.get()>=1:
        Manapoints.set(10)
def Strengt(event=None):
    if rebirth.get()==1:
        Strength.set(1),  counter.set(counter.get() + 1)
def Strengthup(event=None):
    if rebirth.get()>=2:
        Strength.set(Strength.get()+1), 
skillpoint.set(skillpoint.get()-1)
```

I expect after using the skill point for every click to do 2,3,4 and so on the more i upgrade it. Right now i have no idea how to set that up

Comment: if you have a strenght-stat that is 3 - and want to increase it by its own value ... what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to double strength every time it is clicked, this what I got from your question, if i'm wrong please let me know what you actually mean.

Here is a basic function to double strength:

```py
def Strengthup(event=None):
    if rebirth.get()>=2:
        Strength.set(Strength.get()+1), skillpoint.set(skillpoint.get()-1)
        counter.set(counter.get() + Strength.get())
```

From what I understand, this is the solution you want.

A Counter that adds 1% of counter to counter after adding +50

```py
def big_click():
    counter.set(counter.get()+50)
    counter.set(counter.get() + counter.get()*0.01//1)
    Manapoints.set(Manapoints.get()-10)
```

Comment: i'm still only getting 1 added to my counter everytime. i want after i upgrade it once for every click to be 2 then if i upgrade it again for every click to be 3 and so on. at the moment its always onclick adds 1 to counter and i want the strength upgrade to buff that.

Comment: i wasnt asking how to double it i want a function that will make my onclick do more then 1 everything i upgrade strength

Comment: So you want, everytime you click on a strength stat, to add 1, 2, 3, 4..., n to the counter, I'll update my answer now. I think I know what you want, but I might still be confused.

Comment: i ran it with that but when i try to upgrade strength i get this error message. sorry im a bit new at this http://prntscr.com/nqqftz           i havnt used + strength.get()) before (or something like that) so i'm not sure how to fix this. i did try making it counter.set(counter.get()+Strength.set(Strength.get())) but that didnt work either

Comment: idk if its a format thing or why i can't get the upgrade function to work correctly

Comment: never mind i fixed that but upgrade still not working correctly

Comment: @tmanrocks999 I just checked your code, do you have a function called `Strength(event=None)` and a variable called `Strength`, because this will cause an issue and might be why you are getting the error, because Strength is seen as a function, which would not have the `.set()` method.

Comment: i got it to work   http://prntscr.com/nqqhq5       I put that function up top with a if statement under my first on click. thanks so much for the help

Comment: yea i did notice that i had it at one point. it was Strengt at one point but some reason i changed it to Strength on accident

Comment: @MathewGadsden i would make a new question but if i wanted to make a function that adds 50 to counter then + 1% of total counter( would be like a skill) is it possible? something like                                                                                
    def Bigclick                                                             
           counter.set(counter.get()+50), counter.set(counter.get()+1% 
          counter.get())),Manapoints.set(Manapoints.get()-10)

Comment: or (1/100) but idk how to make that tie to counter so it adds 1% of counter to counter

Comment: I added a big click function to the answer, that should do the trick, just remember 1% of 51, is less than one, so it won't actually add anything if the counter is low enough.